# Counting number of times leap motion gesture is made

Tags: wpf

i'm trying to count the number of times a gesture is made using leap motion and WPF using c#. I am having an application that whenever the bug is hit, it will calculate a score. This is my code now but the count is wrong. I have done some research and it says that because it also counted the process of doing the gesture. Please help! Any advice? Do let me know if you know of any other simpler way to count the number of times the gesture is made??

---

```
private void ListenerOnOnGestureMade(GestureList gestureList)

    {
        foreach (var gesture in gestureList)

        {
            if (gesture.Type == Gesture.GestureType.TYPECIRCLE || gesture.Type == Gesture.GestureType.TYPESWIPE)

            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>

                    {
                        SwipeGesture swipeGesture = new SwipeGesture(gesture);
                        var storyboard = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("finger-animation");
                        storyboard.Begin();

                        TryKillBugs(finger, 100, 60);



                    });
            }
```

---

```
     private void TryKillBugs(UIElement image, int width, int height)

    {
        var fingerRect = new Rect

        {
            Location = image.PointToScreen(new Point(180, 0)),
            Height = 200,
            Width = 200
        };

        foreach (var bug in bugs)
        {
            var bugRect = new Rect
            {
                Location = bug.PointToScreen(new Point(180, 0)),
                Height = bug.ActualHeight,
                Width = bug.ActualWidth
            };

            if (fingerRect.IntersectsWith(bugRect))


                bug.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            _killings++;

        score.Text = (_killings).ToString();




        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counter incrementation should be inside `if`, your code is actually counting all bugs on screen

```
if (fingerRect.IntersectsWith(bugRect))
 {
    bug.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    _killings++;
 }
```